# Permission denied when running Console/cake from Vagrant VM

Tags: cakephp, vagrant, puphpet

I've used PuPHPet to configure a Vagrant VM (box: puphpet/debian75-x64) for use with CakePHP.

I `vagrant ssh` into the vm, and go to `/var/www/example.dev/app/`, and from that folder I try to run `Console/cake`.

Result => `-bash: Console/cake: Permission denied`.

I've tried `chmod 777`-ing just about everything, but to no avail.

What do I need to do to make the cake command work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, after doing this(so making it executable) it worked

```
chmod +x app/Console/cake
```

edit: you will need root access to do so

Comment: This is not working for me. (I'm still getting `Permission denied`.)

 `ls -l` gives: 
`-rwxrw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 1368 Jan 15 13:28 cake*`

Comment: @stefanb, are you logged in as root or do you have root access ?

Comment: Oh, duh! No, I was logged in as default `vagrant` user. Doing a `sudo su` after login, and then your `chmod` command above worked.